# Using call_user_function to access parent method in PHP

Tags: php, polymorphism

Is there any way, in PHP, to call methods from a parent class using the arbitrary-argument `call_user_func_array`? Essentially, I want to write a little bit of boilerplate code that, while slightly less optimal, will let me invoke the parent to a method arbitrarily like this:

```
function childFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = null) {
    // I do other things to override the parent here...

    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array(array(parent, __FUNCTION__), $args); // how can I do this?
}
```

Is this an odd hack? Yeah. I will be using this boilerplate in many places, though, where there's likely to be error in transcribing the method args properly, so the tradeoff is for fewer bugs overall.

Comment: I would bet that a construction like this would be more likely to cause bugs, because `call_user_func_array` and friends are somewhat magical. Something tells me there is probably a better solution, but the problem isn't clear enough to me to see it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can call any method on a parent class, as long as it is not overloaded closer to the class of the instance. Just use `$this->methodName(...)`

For slightly more advanced magic, here's a working example of what you seem to want:

**Please note that i do not believe this to be a good idea**

```
class MathStuff
{
    public function multiply()
    {
        $total = 1;
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach($args as $order => $arg)
        {
            $total = $total * $arg;
        }
        return $total;
    }
}
class DangerousCode extends MathStuff
{
    public function multiply()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();

        $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
        $parent = $reflector->getParentClass();
        $method = $parent->getMethod('multiply');
        return $method->invokeArgs($this, $args);
    }
}


$danger = new DangerousCode();
echo $danger->multiply(10, 20, 30, 40);
```

Basically, this looks up the method `MathStuff::multiply` in the method lookup table, and executes its code on instance data from a `DangerousCode` instance.

Answer (score 31):

Try either one of

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::' . __FUNCTION__), $args);
```

or

```
call_user_func_array(array('parent', __FUNCTION__), $args);
```

... depending on your PHP version. Older ones tend to crash slightly, careful :)

Comment: [Both of these will work in `PHP 5.3+`](http://3v4l.org/sv4no). However, in older versions (update your system!), you have to [1. set `func_get_args` to a variable first (and not directly as `call_user_func_array(.., func_get_args())`, and secondly you can only use the first example.](http://3v4l.org/iCJ3e)

Comment: First method (`array($this, 'parent::' . __FUNCTION__)`) will lead to infinite recursion if you extend from class where you use `call_user_func_array` to call parent. Use second method, it works ok.

Comment: As of PHP 8.2, both will throw a deprecated notice